# When to use 'return' in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning about javascript using various books and I'm noticing that I can't find an adequate explanation of when, exactly, you use return. I understand that you use it when you want to return a value from a function, but then there's examples such as this from Javascript: The Good Parts:

```
var quo = function(status) {
    return {
        get_status: function() {
            return status;
        }
    };
};

var myQuo = quo("amazed");

document.writeln(myQuo.get_status());
```

Why does status have to be returned when it is already available to the quo function as an argument? In other words, why does simply

```
return {
    get_status: status;
}
```

not work?

Another example on the page immediately following:

```
var add_the_handlers = function(nodes) {
    var helper = function(i) {
        return function(e) {
            alert(i);
        };
    };
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i<nodes.length; i+=1) {
        nodes[i].onclick = helper(i);
    }
};
```

Why are we returning alert(i) within a function instead of simply putting alert(i)?

Comment: i think you're confusing delayed execution with immediate. `function(){ alert() }` and `alert()` aren't the same thing. Also, if you made it `get_status: status` so now it's a property and not a method (so `myQuo.get_status` instead of `myQuo.get_status()`) and also is read-only instead of being modifiable.

Comment: Example two: you don't want to alert immediately, you want to alert later... You're not returning `alert(I)`, you're returning a function that calls `alert`.

Comment: Why does it pass "e" to that function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
return {
    get_status: status
}
```

would not define a getter, that is a function returning the underlying value. It would only define a property.

You would use it as

```
var status = quo.get_status;
```

And any user could change the status with

```
quo.get_status = 'new status directly changed';
```

One of the reason to use

```
return {
    get_status: function() {
        return status;
    }
};
```

is that it makes `status` private : the users of the `quo` object can't change the internal `status` property of the `quo` object, they can only read it with

```
var status = quo.get_status();
```

Answer (score 1):

What you see in this example is closure demonstration ([see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)) and `status` is saved inside object like private variable.

Answer (score 1):

I won't argue about why the code is as it is -it seems overly complicated to me too- but down to the technical side of things:

```
return {
    get_status: function() {
        return status;
    }
};
```

This will return a function in property get_status, that the caller of quo can call whenever he pleases (x.get_status()).

```
return {
    get_status: status;
}
```

This isn't valid javascript, if you adjust it to

```
return {
    get_status: status
};
```

quo will return an object with a single string property named get_status instead. And that'll work too! You will simply retrieve the value differently.

Check out the following (not very elegant) JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edw6a/1/

Answer (score 1):

The first example might be useful, if for instance you wanted to add some constraints on the `status`. Notice, that get_status is not meant to be called from within `quo`.

```
var quo = function(status) {
    return {
        get_status: function() {
            return status;
        }
        set_status: function(newValue) {
            if (newValue === 2 || newValue === 0) {
               status = newValue;
            }
        }
    };
};
```

The second is an example of a "function maker". Helper will return a different function depending on the value passed. Later the example binds these "made" functions to click events. Simply writing `alert(i);` would create alerts while in the loop.